# fontsize of chapterstyle{article} in memoir class

Tags: memoir, chapters, fontsize, article

I'm using the chapterstyle `article` in my document. However I want to customize the style, i.e., make my own style. Is there any way to find out the exact font size, spacings above and below etc. that the chapterstyle `article` uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `article` chapter style is

```
\makechapterstyle{article}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\quad}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}}
```

It starts by loading the default chapter style as a basis and then modifies it.

The `\beforechapskip` parameter is set to 3.5ex with some stretching and shrinking. The `\chapterheadstart` hook is redefined to just do a vertical skip. Then `\afterchapskip` is set (the space below the title).

The hooks `\printchaptername` and `\chapternamenum` are redefined to do nothing (in the default style they would print “Chapter 1”).

The `\chaptitlefont` hook is redefined to choose `\Large` size and bold face. The `\chapnumfont` is set to equal `\chaptitlefont`.

The `\printchapternum` hook is redefined to use the font just chosen for printing the chapter number followed by a quad of space. After the chapter number nothing is done.

In my opinion, the spacing before and after the chapter title block should be rigid, so I'd prefer something like

```
\makechapterstyle{myarticle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{3.5ex}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{2.3ex}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\quad}
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}}
```

which ensures the titles will always be at the same position for all chapters.

The `ex` dimension depends on the font which is current at the moment the skip is inserted; `1ex` is roughly the height of an `x`.