# Vertical Spacing after the Chapter Title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm using a custom chapterstyle in memoir, with a pgfornament flourish below the title. I would like to reduce the spacing between the chapter title and the ornamentation, so that the ornament appears just below the chapter title:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that whatever I need to do will go in the makechapterstyle code, in the line `\renewcommand\afterchaptertitle`, and so far have attempted to adjust using `vskip`, `midchapskip` and `afterchapskip` to no avail. Any ideas?

```
    \documentclass[oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

    \makeatletter
    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
    \usepackage{pgfornament}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \setsecnumdepth{none}
    \maxsecnumdepth{none}

    \makechapterstyle{custom}
        {\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
        \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontsize{18}{18}\scshape\centering}
        \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
          \begin{center}
        \pgfornament[scale=0.25]{88}
        \end{center}
        }
        }
    \chapterstyle{custom}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think You have to use `\midchapskip` and `\afterchapskip` along with `\setlength'. I haven't been able to get anything to work thoug. You can take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359972/fontsize-of-chapterstylearticle-in-memoir-class

Comment: the `center` environment adds vertical space above the ornament and below it. I guess you want `{\centering\pgfornament{...}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `center` environment always adds vertical space around itself.

The following uses `\raisebox`  for finetuning.

[image: kittyMemoirChapterstyle]

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mwepage}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

    \makeatletter
    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
    \usepackage{pgfornament}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{lmodern}% added

    \setsecnumdepth{none}
    \maxsecnumdepth{none}

    \makechapterstyle{kitty}
        {\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
        \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}\scshape\centering}
        \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
          \par\centering%
        \raisebox{.1ex}{\pgfornament[scale=0.35]{88}}\par\nobreak\vspace{2ex}
        }
        }
    \chapterstyle{kitty}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}\documentclass[oneside,english,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

    \makeatletter
    \@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
    \usepackage{pgfornament}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \setsecnumdepth{none}
    \maxsecnumdepth{none}

    \makechapterstyle{custom}
        {\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
        \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
        \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontsize{18}{18}\scshape\centering}
        \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{%
          \begin{center}
        \pgfornament[scale=0.25]{88}
        \end{center}
        }
        }
    \chapterstyle{custom}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```